# Reference counting of memoryviews with nogil

Tags: cython, gil, typed-memory-views

I don't quite understand how reference counting is done with memoryviews in large/longer nogil sections. Let's assume basically all my code is nogil, except for the creation of a numpy-array-to-memoryview deep down. The memoryview is returned and used upwards.

A fairly simple example would be

```
import numpy as np

cdef:
    double[::1] mv
    
cdef double[::1] someFun(int nn) nogil:
    cdef:
        double[::1] mvb
    with gil:
        mvb = np.arange(nn, dtype=np.double)
    return mvb

with nogil:
    mv = someFun(30)
    # Here could be MUCH more "nogil" code
    # How is memory management/reference counting done here?
```

I assume when someFun() returns the memoryview the refcount of the numpy array should still be at 1.
How does Cython handle the refcounting afterwards? I mean it's not allowed to change the refcount even if the memoryview/array is dereferenced, right? And how would it know to dereference the memoryview if there were several layers with nogil code above, and maybe unlike to someFun() the memoryview isn't returned upwards?

**EDIT:** So I figured out a rather crude way to do some more testing. My code now looks like this.

```
import numpy as np
cdef extern from "stdio.h":
    int getchar() nogil
    int printf(const char* formatt, ...) nogil

cdef:
    double[::1] mv, mv2 = np.ones(3)
    int ii, leng = 140000000
   
cdef double[::1] someFun(int nn) nogil:
    cdef:
        double[::1] mvb
    with gil:
        mvb = np.ones(nn, dtype=np.double)
    return mvb

with nogil:
    mv = someFun(leng)
    printf("1st stop")
    getchar()
    mv = mv2
    printf("2nd stop")
    getchar()
```

The interesting part for me is that at the 1st stop the array/memoryview `mv` is still allocated, but when I dereference it gets free'd until 2nd stop. I only checked memory usage with `htop` (that's why the array is chosen so large), there is probably a better way.
Obviously that free/refcounting behavior what I want to happen, but it's weird that it does it when it doesn't have the GIL. Maybe memoryviews are not completely nogil?

Can someone explain to if this is reliable behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating reference count of the memoryview in the nogil-block happens the same way your function `someFun` is `nogil`: it acquires gil to update the reference count.

The line

```
with nogil:
     mv = someFun(leng)
```

is translated to the following C-code:

```
__pyx_t_3 = __pyx_f_3foo_someFun(__pyx_v_3foo_leng); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_3.memview)) __PYX_ERR(0, 18, __pyx_L3_error)
__PYX_XDEC_MEMVIEW(&__pyx_v_3foo_mv, 0);
__pyx_v_3foo_mv = __pyx_t_3;
__pyx_t_3.memview = NULL;
__pyx_t_3.data = NULL;
```

in order to bind to a new value, the reference counting for the old value must be updated, which happens in `__PYX_XDEC_MEMVIEW`. Its implementation can be looked up [here](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/58dbcf8414de146f7aefefbd2c12c7c5d42e9644/Cython/Utility/MemoryView_C.c#L515):

```
static CYTHON_INLINE void __Pyx_XDEC_MEMVIEW({{memviewslice_name}} *memslice,
                                             int have_gil, int lineno) {
    ...
    } else if (likely(old_acquisition_count == 1)) {
        // Last slice => discard owned Python reference to memoryview object.
        if (have_gil) {
            Py_CLEAR(memslice->memview);
        } else {
            PyGILState_STATE _gilstate = PyGILState_Ensure();
            Py_CLEAR(memslice->memview);
            PyGILState_Release(_gilstate);
        }
    ...
}
```

which means if we don't have gil (`__Pyx_XDEC_MEMVIEW` called with second argument = `0`), it will be acquired to ensure that the reference counting is done properly.

The consequence of the above is, that rebinding a memory view is not cheap as it needs to acquire the GIL and thus should be avoided in tight nogil-loops.

Comment: It's probably worth adding that in a lot of circumstances it doesn't need to re-acquire the GIL since the memoryview keeps its own internal atomic acquisition count. It's really only in the special case where the acquisition count drops to 0 that it does. To destroy a slice that points to a living memoryview doesn't need to GIL.

Comment: @DavidW you are right. As I don't understand fully what is going on with this `old_acquisition_count` I decided not to go too deep into it. But it is quite interesting, so I will update my answer later on.